# How to include resource bundles in ActionScript Modules using Flex 4.1?

Tags: apache-flex, module, flex4, mxmlc

In the simplest of Flex Projects, create an MXML Flex Module and then load it using the ModuleManager.  No problem.  Create an ActionScript class that extends Module and then configure your project to compile that into a Module.  Load this new module instead.  The project compiles, but crashes when running with the following error:

"Error: Could not find compiled resource bundle 'containers' for locale 'en_US'."

I believe the compiler is failing to compile the required class definitions into ActionScript only module, while it succeeds for the MXML module.  I can see that my skeleton MXML module is slightly larger than my ActionScript module (66KB vs. 45KB).

How can I resolve this problem (if that is indeed the issue)?

Answer (score 0):

A good approach in these sort of situations is to use -keep-generated-actionscript for two projects, one with the mxml approach, and one with the actionscript approach.   You can then compare the code to see what might be missing from one project, but included in another.

Have you tried adding an explicit reference to [ResourceBundle("containers")] to your ActionScript project class?   The mxmlc is different to the compc compiler in behaviour for many valid reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem when compiling a library swc. I was able to fix it by adding the following section to the projects  projectName-config.xml

```
    <include-libraries append="true">
        <library>${flexlib}/locale/{locale}/framework_rb.swc</library>
    </include-libraries>
```

This forces the compiler to include the framework resource bundle for the specified locale.

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was finding out which project - in my case a library - and which class in this library caused this behavior (I needed to realize my last changes - no info from flashbuilder). Then applying the following attribute to the class:

```
[ResourceBundle("containers")]
public class IpChecker {
...
```

That did the trick.